# My Query is returning null even though it is not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I am trying to create a follow system and so far everything is working fine, however I am trying to add a feature where you can request to follow a user, and it is not getting any kind of requests and returning as null even though I have follow request in my database.

My logic is the following. I have a table with the followersId, followingId and PendingStatus which represent either if the follow request was accepted or not (true = waiting to be accepted, false = accepted).

I will leave some of my models used in my code:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
        Follower = new List<FollowUser>();
        Following = new List<FollowUser>();
    } 
    
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public required string FullName { get; set; }
    
    // Follow system
    public ICollection<FollowUser> Follower { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FollowUser> Following { get; set; }
    
    // Account Settings
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; } = false;
}
```

```
public class FollowUser
{
    public string FollowerId { get; set; }
    public string FollowingId { get; set; }

    public required bool PendingStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public AppUser Follower { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public AppUser Following { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my endpoint looks like

```
[HttpGet("follow-requests/{userId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetFollowRequests([FromRoute] string userId)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    
        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest("Failed to find user with the specific id");
        
        var requests =  await _userManager.Users
            .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
            .SelectMany(u => u.Following)
            .Where(f => f.PendingStatus == true && f.FollowingId == userId)
            .ToListAsync();
        
        if (requests.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return Ok("You don't have any follow requests");
        return Ok(requests);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if I have understood your logic but are you sure that _f.FollowingID == userID_ is correct?. Am I wrong If I think that this means you are checking if _user_ is following itself?

Comment: The FollowingId represents the Id of who is being followed and the follower the one who is following. I named on the user perspective

Comment: What happens if you change this _.SelectMany(u => u.Following)_ in _.SelectMany(u => u.Follower)_? Beside, you have already extracted the _userID_ in the first line, you can shortcut the whole linq expression using directly _user_

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried what you said and now I am getting this error

System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.Follower.FollowerId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I eventually got it right. What happens is that I wasn't including my Followers which makes it not querying anything from the database. Here is how my query is now:

```
var requests = await _dbContext.FollowUsers
            .Include(f => f.Follower)
            .Where(f => f.FollowingId == userId && f.PendingStatus == true)
            .Select(f => f.Follower)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow up with your answer Mateus, By default EF Core has Lazy loading enabled. which means that data won't be loaded until it is requested. Here's [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) information regarding EF Core. You will be able to check what other kind of loading strategies exist.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Thank you very much!